# Dealing with transparent objects in a PDF for Mozilla's built-in PDF reader

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, adobe-acrobat

Anyone have clever solutions for drop-shadows from InDesign that are being uploaded in .pdf to a website? I've just learned that the new Firefox built-in reader doesn't support it, known issue ([Mozilla Support showing issue](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/954469)).

I tried PDF/X-1a which fixed the shadow issue but one of the more complex sections gets thin white boxes around objects. Same thing when I just opened the PDF and did a Print to PDF.

Only other thing I can think of is opening each page in photoshop, flattening, and combining which obviously isn't ideal for text quality or workflow. This is only an 8 page document so I could do it. Thought maybe one of you knows a solution.

Comment: You can also check your `PDF Export > Advanced > Transparency Flattener` settings, but if you specified PDF/X-1a, it should already be set to the highest setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1

To allow text to still be searchable as text, you could take all of your graphic elements into Photoshop to flatten and re-import back to InDesign as a bitmap image background.

### Option 2

Or, if you don't care as much about the selcectable/searchable text, a quicker route would be to open your PDF in Acrobat Pro, and `File > Save As Other > Image > JPG`. This will save each page as a separate JPG file to a folder you specify.
Then just click `File > Create > Combine Files into a Single PDF` and grab all of those JPGs you created.

---

Ultimately though, it sounds like a known Firefox viewer problem. Any 'solution' is really just a workaround to better support users on that browser.

---

### EDIT

If using **Option 2**, you can adjust quality settings by clicking the `Settings` button below the filename in the `Save As` window:
[image: 'Save As' window]
...and then adjusting the quality settings (in red), and perhaps even the resolution settings (in yellow) if additional clarity is required:
[image: JPEG Settings window]
Increasing these settings will obviously result in a larger file size, but will also make your text more readable.
For maximum clarity, you'd want to go with **Option 1** though. Although more time consuming, you'll get perfectly legible text at a fraction of the filesize compared to having rasterized text (like in Option 2).

Comment: Doing it this method doesn't give enough control over image quality. Whether I do jpg or even tiff the text ends up being way too low resolution.

Comment: @Ryan - Please see my revised answer for additional information on improving the readability of your document.

Comment: thanks but I already played with the settings, its just not a good enough text quality. I'll mark this the answer anyways since it may help someone else.